# How to change back in default raspbian desktop preference?

Tags: screen, raspberry-pi-desktop

This is what I did, I changed something in the repository listing and my desktop suddenly changed after a reboot. It looks good now but it is using more processor and increasing the heat of my board. How may I get back to my default desktop preference(environment)?

Comment: What is the repository listing? How do you changed it? Is there a file to edit? Do you mean `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: yes. you are right

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list`? Please edit your question and paste the content of the two files into it.