# Octave is not working in raspbian

Tags: raspbian, gui, pi-4

I am using Raspberry Pi 4 for one month.
I installed octave today by writing
sudo apt install octave
It installed correctly.
But the gui is not working. I can only use  it with terminal . But when I am trying to use the gui something like this is happening[image: or]

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by 'not working'? What are you expecting to happen that doesn't?

Comment: take a look at the left side of the image. it is blurred and the whole gui is hanged

Comment: Is this the same system referred to in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/104276/8697 ?

Comment: yes. it is indeed

Comment: Then don't waste our time - fix the original problem first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change back in default raspbian desktop preference?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104276/how-to-change-back-in-default-raspbian-desktop-preference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo chmod g+s /usr/bin/octave
```

This trick solve the issue

Comment: For posterity, why that works: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#When_set_on_an_executable_file

Answer (score 1):

Octave needs a sudo/su permission before it works correctly.
I found this problem 3 days ago. Last night I coincidentally wrote
sudo octave
and found something was different. Then I wrote
sudo octave --force-gui 
and then the octave was good to use. And also the gui interface was changed too. Now I am working fine with octave.
If anyone is using raspbian buster they should try it too .